# How to post a JSON with new Apple Swift Language

Tags: ios, json, post, swift

I'm (trying to) learn the Swift's Apple language. I'm at Playground and using Xcode 6 Beta. I'm trying to do a simple JSON Post to a local NodeJS server. I already had googled about it and the major tutorials explain how to do it in a project, not at PLAYGROUND, than don't write stupid thinks like: "google it" or "it's obvious" or "look this link" or never-tested-and-not-functional-code

This is what i'm trying:

```
var request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:3000"), cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5)

var response : NSURLResponse?
var error : NSError?

NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)
```

I had tried:

```
var dataString = "some data"

var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://posttestserver.com/post.php"))
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

let data = (dataString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

var requestBodyData: NSData = data
request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData

var connection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: nil, startImmediately: false)

println("sending request...")
connection.start()
```

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nate's answer was great but I had to change the request.setvalue for it to work on my server

```
// create the request & response
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://requestb.in/1ema2pl1"), cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5)
var response: NSURLResponse?
var error: NSError?

// create some JSON data and configure the request
let jsonString = "json=[{\"str\":\"Hello\",\"num\":1},{\"str\":\"Goodbye\",\"num\":99}]"
request.HTTPBody = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

// send the request
NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)

// look at the response
if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
    println("HTTP response: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
} else {
    println("No HTTP response")
}
```

Comment: At this line I am getting Excepted Declaration                                  request.HTTPBody = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true) But it is already declared.

Answer (score 12):

It looks like you have all the right pieces, just not in quite the right order:

```
// create the request & response
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://requestb.in/1ema2pl1"), cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5)
var response: NSURLResponse?
var error: NSError?

// create some JSON data and configure the request
let jsonString = "json=[{\"str\":\"Hello\",\"num\":1},{\"str\":\"Goodbye\",\"num\":99}]"
request.HTTPBody = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

// send the request
NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)

// look at the response
if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
    println("HTTP response: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
} else {
    println("No HTTP response")
}
```

Comment: Nate, i tried your code and it's outputted:

"2014-07-05 12:05:24.125 PlaygroundStub_sim[1023:194623] ***createStorageTaskManagerForPath:withIdentifier failed: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4099.)" (The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.) UserInfo=0x10bb2fb70 {NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.}; {
    NSDebugDescription = "The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.";
}
HTTP response: 200"

Comment: @CodeWarrior I'm having the same issue! Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a little different approach using asynchronous request. You can use synchronous approach this way too but since everyone above used synchronous request, I thought show asynchronous request instead. Another thing is it seems cleaner and easier this way.

```
    let JSONObject: [String : AnyObject] = [
        "name" : name,
        "address" : address,
        "phone": phoneNumber
    ]

    if NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(JSONObject) {
        var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
        let url = "http://tendinsights.com/user"

        var err: NSError?

        request.URL = NSURL(string: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(JSONObject, options:  NSJSONWritingOptions(rawValue:0), error: &err)

        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue()) {(response, data, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {

                println("error")

            } else {

                println(response) 

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any idea on how to include a JSON array as one of hte JSON objects of the array? I'm constructing a JSON string and adding it as the value of one of my JSON objects but this fails (scape characters are parsed). My server is logging \"[{\"Key\":\"Value\"}]\"