# How to POST JSON data using NSURLSession in swift

Tags: json, post, swift, nsurlsession

I am stuck with the below code. How do I set the param and in post method?

```
let params:[String:Any] = [
        "email" : usr,
        "userPwd" : pwdCode]

let url = NSURL(string:"http://inspect.dev.cbre.eu/SyncServices/api/jobmanagement/PlusContactAuthentication")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

request.HTTPBody = params<what should do for Json parameter>


let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    data, response, error in

    if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
        if httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
            println("response was not 200: \(response)")
            return
        }
    }
    if error {
        println("error submitting request: \(error)")
        return
    }

    // handle the data of the successful response here
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: I think it's not clear what the problem is - could you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry for my language...I want to adjust a parameter <request.HTTPBody = params<what should do for Json parameter> for post method ..but i dont know how to do that?If you can edit my code and show it to me than it ll be good

Comment: The answer depends on `usr` and `pwdCode` types. string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to post a JSON with new Apple Swift Language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566180/how-to-post-a-json-with-new-apple-swift-language)

Answer (score 5):

if I understand the question correctly

```
var configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
var session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration)
var usr = "dsdd"
var pwdCode = "dsds"
let params:[String: AnyObject] = [
    "email" : usr,
    "userPwd" : pwdCode ]

let url = NSURL(string:"http://localhost:8300")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
var err: NSError?
request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.allZeros, error: &err)

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    data, response, error in

    if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
        if httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
            println("response was not 200: \(response)")
            return
        }
    }
    if (error != nil) {
        println("error submitting request: \(error)")
        return
    }

    // handle the data of the successful response here
    var result = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: nil) as? NSDictionary
    println(result)
}
task.resume()
```

I would suggest using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). See for example, [Posting JSON data using AFNetworking 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487184/posting-json-data-using-afnetworking-2-0).

Comment: What does AFNetworking give you over NSURLSession? I used to use AFNetworking but NSURLSession seems remarkably similar to what it used to do.

Comment: @AdamEberbach, AFNetworking (2.x) is built on top of NSURLSession to provide some abstractions that make your life easier. For example, it may parse the data as JSON (the headers in the response usually say the type of data). There are many other things; you can start from this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial and then visit the docs to see further usage. However, I agree that sometimes you don't need to bring the big guns if you don't need them :)


-Another thing worth noting - If you want to target iOS 6 you might find AFNetworking to be your best option

Comment: This was so helpful, I battled with this issue for a good amount of time, finally got it right thanks to this answer.

Comment: your link is not for swift code its objective c code.please provide afnetworking link for swift code

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can set **parameters** and send a **POST** request, easy approach using **Alamofire**.

- **Swift 2.2**

  ```
  let URL = NSURL(string: "https://SOME_URL/web.send.json")!
  let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
  mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

  let parameters = ["api_key": "______", "email_details": ["fromname": "______", "subject": "this is test email subject", "from": "support@apple.com", "content": "<p> hi, this is a test email sent via Pepipost JSON API.</p>"], "recipients": ["_________"]]

  do {
      mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
  } catch {
      // No-op
  }

  mutableURLRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

  Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest)
      .responseJSON { response in
          print(response.request)  // original URL request
          print(response.response) // URL response
          print(response.data)     // server data
          print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

          if let JSON = response.result.value {
              print("JSON: \(JSON)")
          }
  }
  ```