# Read JSON in PHP from Swift

Tags: php, swift

I am having trouble with my php file reading JSON data.  I use swift to send data to a server. I encode the request and when I send it as a string everything works fine. My String that works fine in PHP looks like this

`id=e61db0&time=Feb 13, 2015` so this works fine when received by PHP

However, when I use dictionary and encode NSData my PHP file is not able to read it. I decoded the data that I send and it looks like that:

`{"id":"e61db0", "time":"Feb 13, 2015"}` this doesn't work when received by php

For my request setting headers I do this:

```
var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(ui_image, 0.5)
let base64encoded = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.allZeros)
var params = ["id": uid, "time": date, "comment": img_com_e, "image": base64encoded]
var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"    
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
var error: NSError?
        request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: .allZeros, error: &error)
        if let error = error {
            println("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error -> Void in
            let res = response as NSHTTPURLResponse!;
            NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);

        if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
        {
            var responseData:NSString  = NSString(data: data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            return_val = responseData
            NSLog("Response ==> %@", responseData);
        } else {
            return_val = "bad"
            //println(return_val)
        }

    }

    dataTask.resume()
```

Not sure what is going on. Does my server PHP file does not recognize that it is JSON data and can't accept $_POST['id']. Should I set my headers somehow differently?

Comment: take a look on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566180/how-to-post-a-json-with-new-apple-swift-language

Comment: Hi Kim, I saw that. that example has it as a string. I updated my question a little. My 'params' is Dictionary

Comment: Have you tried `json_decode()`?

Comment: I was thinking that I can set it somehow to that it reads JSON directly, since I have same php file reading info from android, I guess I just set it up little bit modified version with Json_decode() for iOS. It looks like I am sending info from Android little bit differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your php code?

If you send `Content-Type: application/json`

You should read `php://input` not `$_POST`

try:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data);
echo $data["id"];
```